# Java - Having trouble converting char to string (beginner)

Tags: java, string, char

I am trying to iterate through each character in a string that is inputted and check if any letter is `a`.

Here is my Java code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Input 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input;
        input = in.nextLine();

        for (int i=0; i<input.length(); i++)
        {
            char chararcter = input.charAt(i);
            String s = Character.toString(character);   //the error is here

            if (s.equals("a"))
            {
                System.out.println("You typed an A.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For reference, here is a Python analog.

```
input=raw_input()
for i in range (0,len(input)):
    if input[i] == "a":
        print "You typed an A."
```

---

I apologize for the simplistic nature of this question; I'm very new to Java. Thank you for helping.

Comment: You also could compare it without storing it into a String with `input.charAt(i) == 'a'`

Comment: I've flagged this question for closure because the problem is caused by a **simple typographical error** (you've mis-spelt `character` in your declaration).

Answer (score 4):

You've change the spelling in your declaration.

```
char character = input.charAt(i); // <-- not chararcter (extra rc).
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to convert character to String. just simply do character comparison.

```
if (chararcter == 'a')
{
   System.out.println("You typed an A.");
}
```